# jQuery Ajax POST changes Content-Type in Firefox

Tags: ajax, jquery, firefox, content-type

I'm making an Ajax call to POST a collection of fields, objects, and arrays to PHP.  9 times out of 10 this works just fine.  But when submitting the same request a number of times (no changes to the data) the request will occasionally be sent with Content-Type: text/plain or text/html rather than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, causing issues in my PHP.  JSON might be more advisable, but can anyone think of why this could be happening?

- This is not a cross domain request.
- This only happens in Firefox.
- I don't think I need to specify the Content-Type since Ajax will default.
- I explicitly call `$.param()` but don't think I need to.
- I expect JSON in return.

  ```
  $.ajax({url: action,
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     data: $.param($(domElement).data()),
     complete: function() {
        // Cleanup
     },
     success: function(data) {
        // Handle success.
     },
     error: function() {
        // Handle error
     }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this only happens in Firefox, but does it help if you set the content type manually?

```
$.ajax({url: action,
   type: "POST",
   contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
   dataType: "json",
   data: $.param($(domElement).data()),

   complete: function() {
      // Cleanup
   },
   success: function(data) {
      // Handle success.
   },
   error: function() {
      // Handle error
   }
});
```

Comment: Trying that.  It seems to reduce the number of occurrences, but I still see them.  I wonder if it has something to do with how or when Ajax determines the content type and the fact that my data is attached to a DOM object via jQuery.

Comment: That seems to be right: if I use .val() instead of .data on the dom element, I get the content-type headers.